# Anonymous access to SharePoint resource returns 401 Unauthorized if Content-Type header is soap+xml

Tags: content-type, anonymous-authentication

There is a simple handler created, hosted in SharePoint site. For that handler and for affected lists Anonymous Access is configured. **Everything is working smoothly** when I submit a POST request without authentication and **without Content-Type header**. BUT when I add Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8, SharePoint server return 401 Unauthorized error and also requests NTLM authentication mode. But it should accept anonymous requests.
**It fails only when Content-Type is application/soap+xml.** Request:

```
POST https://listetner.ashx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 527
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope>content</s:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: b8dea544-2792-4dfd-bd88-98c8dab71e62
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6123
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 21:08:31 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

401 UNAUTHORIZED
```